# Getting React error: "children" not defined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create functionality in which when I am clicking on one button it show the text for all the button which are in the loop so I tried a method in which I have used the useState function i.e `const [CouponCode, setCouponCode] = useState(Array.from({length:children.length}).fill(false))` here I am getting an error of children not defined then I used "this.props.children.length" still I am getting error for props

```
import  React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from"axios";
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import { Box, Grid, ListItemText } from '@mui/material';



function FetchData(props) {
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);
  // const [isTextHidden, setTextHidden] = useState(true)
  const [CouponCode, setCouponCode] = useState(Array.from({length:children.length}).fill(false))
  // const [texts, setTexts] = useState({})

  // const email=localStorage.getItem('email')
//   useEffect(() => {
//     getData();
// }, []);

// function getData() { 
//   axios({
//     method: "GET",
//     url:`http://127.0.0.1:5000/coupons`, 
//     headers: {
//       Authorization: 'Bearer ' + props.token
//     }
//   })
//   .then((response) => {
//       console.log(response)
//     const res =response.data
//     res.access_token && props.setToken(res.access_token)
//     setRecords(res.data)
//   }).catch((error) => {
//     if (error.response) {
//       console.log(error.response)
//       console.log(error.response.status)
//       console.log(error.response.headers)
//       }
//   })
// }
  useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/coupons",
      headers: {
        // Authorization:'Bearer ' + props.token
      },
      params: {},
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("response :", response.data);
        // const res =response.data
        // res.access_token && props.setToken(res.access_token)
        setRecords(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
  // const logged = localStorage.getItem('email');
  // const handleClick=useCallback((index)=>{
  //   if (logged) {
  //     setTexts(prevState=>{
  //       const coupArr=[...prevState];
  //       coupArr[index]=!coupArr[index]
  //       return coupArr
  //     });

      

      
  //   } else {
  //     window.alert("Please login to access the Code")
      
  //   }
  // })
  return (
    <div styles={{padding:30}}>
      <Grid container spacing={8} justifyContent="center">
        {records?.map((list,index)=>(
          <Grid item xs={10} key={index}>
            <Card variant='outlined'sx={{display:"block",width:"70vw"}}>
              <Box sx={{ width: '95px', height: '100px', boxShadow: 0, 
            margin: '10px',top:"0" }}>
              <img width="95px" height="100px" alt='Logo' srcSet={list.title_logo}/>
              <ListItemText
              sx={{display:"inline",position:"absolute"}}
              primaryTypographyProps={{fontSize:"2rem"}}
              secondaryTypographyProps={{fontSize:"1.1rem",style: {
                whiteSpace: 'wrap',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                textOverflow: 'ellipsis'}}}
              primary={
                <div>
                  <span>{list.offer_title}</span>
                </div>
              }
              secondary={list.description}/>
              
              {list.type_of_voucher==="Coupons"? 
              <button onClick={()=> setCouponCode(prevState => {
                const tutorsArr = [...prevState];
                tutorsArr[index] = !tutorsArr[index]
                return tutorsArr;})}>{CouponCode[index] ? "Get Coupon Code":""}</button>
              :<button style={{display:'inline-flex',float:'right'}} onClick={()=> setCouponCode(prevState => {
                const tutorsArr = [...prevState];
                tutorsArr[index] = !tutorsArr[index]
                return tutorsArr;})}>{CouponCode[index] ?"Get Deals":""} </button>}
              {/* <Button >Get Coupon code</Button> */}
              {/* <Button style={{display:'inline-flex',float:'right'}}>Get Deals</Button> */}

            </Box>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        ))};

      </Grid>
    </div>
    
  );
};




export default FetchData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `children` *isn't* defined in that code.

It looks like you're trying to make use of [the `children` prop](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#passing-jsx-as-children).  To use it, you need to get it from `props` just like any other prop:

```
{ length: props.children.length }
```

**Alternatively,** instead of using a single `props` argument to the component, you can de-structure the props in the function header:

```
function FetchData({ children }) {
```

Note of course that you'd also need to de-structure any other props you're looking to use as well.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest the second alternative as the OP takes the length of a specific variable. They should know what the children is in the first place.

Comment: And the first solution is something that op already tried and it still is undefined.

Comment: @knoxgon: *"And the first solution is something that op already tried"* - Not according to the question they didn't.  They tried `this.props.children.length`, which is also incorrect because `this` isn't really meaningful in this context (and `this.props` is, as expected, `undefined`).  At best they were copying/pasting code from a class-based component.

Comment: That's what I suspect as well. But I would still issue the OP to figure out what they try to do. Copy and pasting yet fixing the code at the same time will indeed introduce more problems later on. I would encourage them to figure out what they try to achieve and learn.

Comment: added children and de-structured wherever I have used props but still am getting the error of Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: @ShivamMisra: What is the actual and exact updated code?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, including how this component is being used in the first place?

Comment: How do you call `FetchData`? Post the code where you render FetchData

Comment: updated the code using function FetchData({children}) {

Comment: @ShivamMisra: Which [demonstrably works](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-resonance-4676cs?file=/src/FetchData.js).  Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you are observing.  It's entirely possible, even likely, that you've encountered other, separate problems in your code.

Comment: @David I am having error in this line of code "const [CouponCode, setCouponCode] = useState(Array.from({length:children.length}).fill(false))" which is giving me error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

Comment: @ShivamMisra: Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @David I am not getting what exactly you asking for I have shared the whole code and the error I am facing and at which line I am facing

Comment: @ShivamMisra: What I'm asking for is a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  This would include specifically and only the code which produces the problem (and not all of the additional unrelated code shown in the question), including the code which uses this component and how the component is being used, in a format which can be executed to demonstrate the problem.  Ideally this would be in a code snippet in the question above, but failing that could also be in an off-site example such as Code Sandbox.  The problem may be something outside of what you're describing here.

Comment: @David creating the problem "const [CouponCode, setCouponCode] = useState(Array.from({length:children.length}).fill(false))" and it uses this component <Button style={{display:'inline-flex',float:'right'}}onClick={()=> setCouponCode(prevState => {
                const tutorsArr = [...prevState];
                tutorsArr[index] = !tutorsArr[index]
                return tutorsArr;})}>{CouponCode[index] ? "Get Coupon Code":""}</Button>

Comment: @ShivamMisra: That is not a runnable [mcve]. A [mcve] can be executed as-is to demonstrate exactly the error or problem described. With a [mcve] we would be able to observe the problem and use the [mcve] to better understand and diagnose the problem. The [mcve] would particularly indicate problems which aren't what/where you expect them to be. You are encouraged to create a [mcve] instead of just continuing to vaguely describe the problem. When you have your [mcve], post that [mcve] here and I can use that [mcve] to help you. To learn more about a [mcve], please visit the link: [mcve]

Comment: @ShivamMisra: ***For example***, here's a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates that the suggestion in this answer works as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-resonance-4676cs?file=/src/FetchData.js

Comment: @David please check this link here's a runnable minimal reproducible example https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-mcnulty-yptg7l?file=/src/FetchData.js

Comment: @ShivamMisra: And in what way is that code failing?  When that page loads, I see no UI and no error message.  (Aside from the obvious network errors because the AJAX request clearly won't do anything there.)  What exactly is the problem?  In fact... If you look at the console you will see that there is no error when using `children` and that the console successfully logs the resulting array.  The code you're showing demonstrates that the answer given here works as expected.  Did you bother testing it before all of this arguing?  Clearly you did not.

Comment: @David the code is failing at this point const [CouponCode, setCouponCode] = useState(Array.from({length:children.length}).fill(false)) giving an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: @ShivamMisra: [Not in my browser it isn't](https://imgur.com/a/xvdx1oN).  Honestly, at this point I can only assume you're not actually trying to solve a problem and are just trying to troll this community.

Comment: @David I am sorry but I tried and am not trolling this community david